# SFDX: Authorise an Org not working

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to authorise an org using VS Code but keep getting the following

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias jandev21 --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
    Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I have tried googling for the issue but couldn't find any fix so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try control+shift+p > authorize org command, or command+shift+p on mac. Also try “sfdx update” maybe you have old version?

Comment: I did try updating sfdx but still the same issue.

Comment: Your command fails,  but does the command palette (gui) work? Can you create a new sfdx project and auth? Does the auth popup a browser window or does it fail before then? check the sfdx-project.json in your current directory for errors, or if youre unsure about sfdx-project.json simply change directory to a known-good project and see if auth works in the new project.

Comment: Root cause might be identical to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312469/sfdx-forceprojectcreate-throwing-error-running-forceprojectcreate-unexpecte?

Comment: Using the command does pop up a browser window but after I enter my username and password I get ERR_REFUSED_CONNECT. So based on one of the solutions I did try to find out if anything is running on port 1717 to kill it and re tried but still no luck. @PeterNoges

Comment: @identigral I did follow that link and tried mom init in my project directory but still getting the same error.

Comment: @rohit maharashi try creating a new sfdx project, that may help narrow down the issue. Any luck?

Comment: @PeterNoges tried creating a new project but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Case the issue was that i had an EMPTY JSON-File in the User Home SFDX Directory. On Windows Machines:

```
C:\Users\[YOUR USERNAME]\.sfdx
```

There is also a Log-File "sfdx.log" which also gives detailled insight into the issue. In my Case there was a code line like this:

```
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"ANONYM-PC","pid":21268,"level":10,"msg":"Setup child 'auth' logger instance","time":"2021-09-07T12:04:49.102Z","v":0}
{"name":"JsonParseError","hostname":"ANONYM-PC","pid":21268,"log":"auth","level":20,"cause":{},"path":"C:\\Users\\ANONYM\\.sfdx\\[REPLACED].json","msg":"","time":"2021-09-07T12:04:49.102Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"ANONYM-PC","pid":21268,"log":"WebOAuthServer","level":20,"msg":"closing server connection","time":"2021-09-07T12:04:49.103Z","v":0}
{"name":"JsonParseError","hostname":"ANONYM-PC","pid":21268,"log":"Login","level":30,"status":1,"message":"Unexpected end of JSON input","exitCode":1,"commandName":"Login","stack":"JsonParseError: Unexpected end of JSON input\n    at Function.create (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\errors.js:52:20)\n    at parseJson (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\json.js:28:39)\n    at Object.parseJsonMap (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\json.js:67:18)\n    at Object.readJsonMap (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\util\\fs.js:203:22)\n    at async AuthInfoConfig.read (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\config\\configFile.js:151:29)\n    at async AuthInfoConfig.init (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\config\\configFile.js:329:9)\n    at async Function.create (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\kit\\lib\\creatable.js:31:9)\n    at async AuthInfo.save (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\authInfo.js:439:24)\n    at async C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\webOAuthServer.js:83:25\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at Login.catch (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:248:67)\n    at async Login._run (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:85:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@oclif\\config\\lib\\config.js:173:24)\n    at async SfdxMain.run (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\main.js:27:9)\n    at async SfdxMain._run (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\command.js:43:20)\n    at async Object.run (C:\\Program Files\\sfdx\\client\\dist\\cli.js:162:47)","warnings":[],"msg":"","time":"2021-09-07T12:04:49.145Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"ANONYM-PC","pid":21268,"log":"WebServer","level":20,"msg":"number of connections open: 0","time":"2021-09-07T12:04:49.170Z","v":0}
```

In case of Web-Login, SFDX checks any existing login in your home directory. if any of these JSON is corrupt the login process fails.

Solution: Remove corrupted files